# Is this format supported: avc1.77.40,mp4a.40.34

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

I'm getting this error when playing an m3u8 file on the Chromecast

```
Uncaught NotSupportedError: Failed to execute 'addSourceBuffer' on 'MediaSource': The type provided ('video/mp2t; codecs="avc1.77.40,mp4a.40.34"') is unsupported.
```

I know in the past I was given a line to replace avc1.66.* with .30 codecs when processing the manifest, should I do the same for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, please do the same and see if that resolves your issue.

Comment: I replaced `avc1.77.40,mp4a.40.34` with `avc1.66.30,mp4a.40.34` and it didn't like it either. I removed the codec part and it loaded one segment file but failed on the second segment file, but I don't know if that is a stream issue or because I removed the codec.